# How to update an item of a list with angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to update a model of type 'SomeModel' in a list of elements of type SomeModel[]

I'm trying to point to the object needed as follow:

```
onChange(args: SomeModel): void {
  let element: SomeModel = this.elements.find(e => e.name === args.name);
  console.log(element) // <-- this prints the right object from the list
  element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args)); // <-- isn't working
```

}

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by word "update"? what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to change the model variables from the list (this.elements)

Comment: do you want to change one of its properties? if so, just change it:
`this.elements.find(e => e.name === args.name).prop = 'newValue'`. or, if you want to follow immutability rules try this: `this.elements = this.elements.map(e => e.name === args.name ? args : e);`;

Comment: I need to overwrite all the properties of the model

Comment: so, what in your understanding does `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args));` do?

Comment: check my long comment. it seems it does what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
onChange(args: SomeModel): void {
  this.elements = this.elements.map(e => {
    if (e.name === args.name){
      return args;
     } 
    return e;
   })
}
```

Comment: spreading into new array is redundant. `.map` already creates a new array

Comment: also `return e = args;` is strange a bit. just `return args` would work the same

Comment: I think this is still buggy because if you don't step into the if statement you will have nulls where e.name does not equal args.name. maybe doing something like Andrei said in his comment `this.elements.map(e => e.name === args.name ? args : e);` or using the filter function to take out the nulls `this.elements.map(e => e.name === args.name ? args : e).filter(e => e);` and be left with only the valid names

Comment: this.kPIElements = this.kPIElements.map(e => e.name === args.name ? e = args : e);
gives the same behaviour.
Thank you guys you have saved my day

Comment: `e = args` is still redundant. just ` ? args : e` would work fine. you are not assigning something here, but returning from `.map` callback.

Comment: @Andrei, I think a page refresh is needed on your part ^^ (it was changed since a while). thx tho

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys,
the complete answer is:

```
onChange(args: SomeModel) void {
this.elements = this.elements.filter(e => e).map(e => e.name === args.name ? args : e);
```

Comment: is it possible to have null elements in your elements array? if not then you don't need the `.filter(e => e)`

Comment: correct you are right, I don't have to because it is declared with variables from the initiation